# Issues with Twig template includes when rendering from a service called from a CP-triggered event

Tags: plugin-development, templating, events, services

I have a listener for the `entries.saveEntry`event that is calling a service, which generates an email from a rendered template. The template is attempting to import macros.

MyaddonPlugin.php::init()

```
craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    if ($event->params['isNewEntry']) {
        craft()->myaddon_emails->generateEmail($event->params['entry']);
    }
});
```

Myaddon_EmailsService.php::generateEmail()

```
$emailHtml = craft()->templates->render('myaddon/email');
```

plugins/myaddon/templates/email.twig

```
{% import '_macros/mymacro' as mymacro % }
```

When I attempt to run this I get this error:

```
Unable to find the template “_macros/mymacro”.
```

When running the same service/render code from a Controller, everything works. It seems like there is a difference with how paths are set or handled in a Controller vs. an event handler. I tried manually setting the template path based on [this page](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates), but same results.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help...but try renaming the .twig files as .html.

Comment: @aberkie - thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't help either. The strange thing is all of this works through a Controller, so my suspicion is that it has something to do with how paths are handled or loaded in Controllers vs. event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what is going wrong here, but here is what I would do to debug this on my end:

1. Simply output the current path the template parser is using in the controller and event handler to see the difference in the values

   ```
   var_dump(craft()->path->getTemplatesPath());
   exit();
   ```
2. If the values are different, you can override the value to do your parsing as your need it like so:

   ```
   // Get the current path and save it
   $oldPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();

   // Set your desired template path
   craft()->path->setTemplatesPath('your/new/path');

   // Render your template and pass some data to it that will be parsed
   craft()->templates->render('your/template', $data = array());

   // Set the old path so Craft can resume as normal and you don't break stuff
   craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($oldPath);
   ```
3. One other option is to try to include your macro like so:

   ```
   {% import 'myplugin/_macros/mymacro' as mymacro % }
   ```

I basically do the exact same thing you are doing with [Postmaster for Craft](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS). I include my own macros, parse templates and strings during event handlers, it all works perfectly for me using the technique I outlined above. Feel free to take a look at my code if you want to see some more advanced examples of this.

On a side note, I bet Postmaster will do exactly what you want to do in regards to sending an email for new entries. You should give it a shot, it has loads of additional features I bet you could use. No less, I do help this solve your problem either way. Sorry this wasn't really an official answer or a guaranteed fix, but I gave it my best shot without seeing all of your code.